# How to get the text based on xml tags in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, tags, pattern-matching, string-matching

A Newbie here!

Can anyone help me to extract the text SAMPLE HEADING between the XML tags? And is there also a way to extract text based on headings 1 to headings 6 present in XML tags? If yes, how to factor it in?
Below is the XML code of it:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000033">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
<w:numPr>
<w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
<w:numId w:val="1"/>
</w:numPr>
<w:ind w:left="520" w:hanging="360"/>
<w:rPr>
<w:b w:val="1"/>
<w:color w:val="000000"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
<w:rPr>
<w:b w:val="1"/>
<w:color w:val="000000"/>
<w:rtl w:val="0"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t xml:space="preserve">SAMPLE HEADING</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the XML file as a dictionary, which would then allow you to parse the dictionary based on the elements of the XML file.

As a sample:

```py
import xmltodict

with open('file.xml') as xml:
  data = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
  xml_file.close()
```

This will yield an ordered dictionary from your XML file:

```
OrderedDict([('w:p',
              OrderedDict([('@w:rsidR', '00000000'),
                           ('@w:rsidDel', '00000000'),
                           ('@w:rsidP', '00000000'),
                           ('@w:rsidRDefault', '00000000'),
                           ('@w:rsidRPr', '00000000'),
                           ('@w14:paraId', '00000033'),
                           ('w:pPr',
                            OrderedDict([('w:pStyle',
                                          OrderedDict([('@w:val',
                                                        'Heading2')])),
                                         ('w:numPr',
                                          OrderedDict([('w:ilvl',
                                                        OrderedDict([('@w:val',
                                                                      '0')])),
                                                       ('w:numId',
                                                        OrderedDict([('@w:val',
                                                                      '1')]))])),
                                         ('w:ind',
                                          OrderedDict([('@w:left', '520'),
                                                       ('@w:hanging', '360')])),
                                         ('w:rPr',
                                          OrderedDict([('w:b',
                                                        OrderedDict([('@w:val',
                                                                      '1')])),
                                                       ('w:color',
                                                        OrderedDict([('@w:val',
                                                                      '000000')]))]))])),
                           ('w:r',
                            OrderedDict([('@w:rsidDel', '00000000'),
                                         ('@w:rsidR', '00000000'),
                                         ('@w:rsidRPr', '00000000'),
                                         ('w:rPr',
                                          OrderedDict([('w:b',
                                                        OrderedDict([('@w:val',
                                                                      '1')])),
                                                       ('w:color',
                                                        OrderedDict([('@w:val',
                                                                      '000000')])),
                                                       ('w:rtl',
                                                        OrderedDict([('@w:val',
                                                                      '0')]))])),
                                         ('w:t',
                                          OrderedDict([('@xml:space',
                                                        'preserve'),
                                                       ('#text',
                                                        'SAMPLE '
                                                        'HEADING')]))]))]))])
```

From this dictionary, you can access the SAMPLE HEADING through:
`data['w:p']['w:r']['w:t']['#text']`